# RecyclerView - horizontal list with vertical scrolling

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I need to display my list similar way as text with line break, with vertical scrolling. So, items should be arranged horizontally and when there's no more room for last item, it should be placed in the next row below. I tried with `GridLayoutManager`, but that's not what I want - it displays columns and I need to provide number of columns.

How can I create layout like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consider using [FlexboxLayout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) library and [`FlexboxLayoutManager`](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout#flexboxlayoutmanager-within-recyclerview) desired to work with `RecyclerView`, looks like it solves exacly your case